# Stored Procedure to return Names with a given first letter via Search function

Tags: c#, sql, search

Tried a query first like this

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE LEFT(NAME, 1) = 'A'
```

which worked fine, but now I want it as a stored procedure and 'A' being replaced by a search term like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procCustomer_SelectByFirstLetter]
    @SearchTerm VARCHAR(50)
AS
SELECT  [Name]

FROM    [dbo].[Customer]
WHERE   LEFT(NAME, 1) = '@SearchTerm'
GO
```

this stored procedure is called by a C# method which uses a dropdown list with all the letters A-Z

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            DataTable customerTable =  Customer.SelectByFirstLetter(Request.QueryString[DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()]);
            CustomerRepeater.DataSource = customerTable;
            CustomerRepeater.DataBind();
            CustomerCountLabel.Text = customerTable.Rows.Count.ToString();            
    }
```

the Reapter shows nothing though when I select a letter from the drop down. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: remove the single quotes around the variable name

Comment: You need to account for the length of the search term.  IE, you can't do LEFT(xxx,1) in the SP.

Comment: See my post below.  Also David's last edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're still using the quoted value, so it looks for a name where the first letter equals the string `"@SearchTerm"`, which of course nothing ever will.

You'll need to remove the quotes:

```
WHERE LEFT(NAME, 1) = @SearchTerm
```

Additionally, you may or may not be aware that you can achieve this with `LIKE`:

```
WHERE NAME LIKE 'A%'
```

... Or

```
WHERE NAME LIKE @SearchTerm + '%'
```

... Where the `%` is wildcard for anything. In this way, passing `A` will search for anything starting with the letter A, but passing `ABC` will search for anything with the letters "ABC", without having to specify the length, as in your `LEFT` function.

**Update**
Additionally, you seem to be passing the parameter to the procedure incorrectly:

```
DataTable customerTable = Customer.SelectByFirstLetter(Request.QueryString[DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()]);
```

Here, you're looking for a key in the QueryString collection, matching your selected value. So if `DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()` yields "A", it'll be looking for `?A=...`. You probably want to use the following instead:

```
DataTable customerTable = Customer.SelectByFirstLetter(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: see my comment to the previous user

Comment: thanks for the info... but still not working. I'm starting to think the info from the dropdownlist isn't being passed on...? does the method look right to you?

Comment: Are you sure you've executed your `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement, so that the changes are saved? Because that code will work (I just tested it).

Comment: Hmm, are you sure `Request.QueryString[DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()]` should not just be `DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()` ? (see my update regarding that)

Comment: ok now I get an error when I select a letter. HTTPException was unhandled by user code. The error occurs at CustomerRepeater.DataBind() and it says System.Data.DataRowView does not contain a property with the name 'CustomerID'. What?! Why is it returning CustomerID

Comment: nevermind got it! including the CustomerId in the stroed procedure SELECT fixed it. Makes sense since the REPEATER needs the customerID to function! <a href='CustomerHome.aspx?CustomerId=<%#Eval("CustomerID") %>'><%#Eval("Name") %>

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
LEFT(NAME, 1) = @SearchTerm
```

instead of

```
LEFT(NAME, 1) = '@SearchTerm'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment on your question, not accounting for the length of the search term may be the issue you are having, but also others have suggested another good method using like instead of left.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procCustomer_SelectByFirstLetter]
    @SearchTerm VARCHAR(50)
AS
SELECT  [Name]

FROM    [dbo].[Customer]
WHERE   LEFT(NAME, LEN(@SearchTerm)) = @SearchTerm
```

That said, on further review, it's likely that this line is your issue:

```
Customer.SelectByFirstLetter(Request.QueryString[DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()]);
```

Request.QueryString[value] is going to give you whatever Request.QueryString[value] is equal to.  I think you really want this?

```
Customer.SelectByFirstLetter(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match the first charachter your SP should look like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procCustomer_SelectByFirstLetter]
    @SearchTerm CHAR(1)  
AS  
    SELECT 
              [Name]
        FROM    
              [dbo].[Customer]  
        WHERE   
              LEFT(NAME, 1) = @SearchTerm
GO
```

More generically you could do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procCustomer_SelectByNameStart]
    @SearchTerm VARCHAR(MAX) /*Use your column width here*/
AS  
    SELECT 
              [Name]
        FROM    
              [dbo].[Customer] C
        WHERE   
              C.[Name] LIKE @SearchTerm + '%'
GO
```

You will probably want to include the primary key of the Customer table in the result set too but I assmue this is omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you filling your DropDownList in the Page_Load-Event?

If yes, verify that this happens in a

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
}
```

block.

The Page_Load is executed before the SelectedIndex_Changed Event, and thus if you're not binding the Dropdown correctly, resetting the value of the Dropdown to the inital value, and not to your search term.